# Release Management vNext component deployment location

Tags: powershell, ms-release-management

Is there a way to modify the target location of the deployments for vNext templates? They all go to the following default location.

C:\Windows\DtlDownloads\ComponentName

Also, is there a way to acquire the name of the vNext deployment component dynamically so that it can be used by a PowerShell script?

I am currently using Update 4.

Answer (score 2):

To override the default location where components are copied on the target machine - you can define a global variable (go to *settings tab -> global configuration variables*) called `applicationpathroot` and give it whatever value you want.

Also, the `ComponentName` variable is available to the powershell scripts.

As a general rule, all the configuration variables that you see on the workflow designer, and the implicit variables that you define with the actions (the +,- icons on the deploy actions) are passed down to the scripts.